# Where are definitions of Rf_lang2 and Rf_lang3?

Tags: r, internals

I am starting to explore source code of R interpreter itself.

I started from src/main/gram.y and src/include/Rinternals.h, and also referred information on the Web( https://marlin-na.github.io/r-api/pairlists/ ). I found it seems to be constructing abstract syntax tree using linked list like data structure.

They are using Rf_lang2, Rf_lang3 and functions begining with Rf_ prefix.

However, I cannot find those definitions of Rf_lang2, Rf_lang3 and Rf_*** functions.

Could you tell me the files of those functions' definitions?

I am browsing source tree at https://github.com/wch/r-source

Comment: The function is defined here https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/f52dfba361b4abde1426dd2751dfb56fcebc58e6/src/include/Rinlinedfuns.h#L711 where it's called `lang2` which was defined as a macro variable to expands to `Rf_lang2` https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/c634fec5214e73747b44d7c0e6f047fefe44667d/src/include/Rinternals.h#L1621

Comment: @MrFlick Thanks, that's what I was looking for! Though I searched many times, I missed the file, Rinlinedfuns.h . Your comment is the best answer.